# Regex has unexpected results. I am new to this, fair warning

Tags: html, regex

The following regex does match what I am looking for, but it will also match all file extensions (just the file extensions) of anything ending with gif|jpg|png

```
webcomic"\ssrc="http://www\.explosm\.net/[a-zA-Z/]+\.gif|png|jpg"\s
```

I am using it on the source of the following page, which is a webcomic that is updated daily:

```
http://www.explosm.net/comics/
```

Today, the end goal would be the following, and only the following:

```
webcomic" src="http://www.explosm.net/db/files/Comics/Kris/lawyer.gif"
```

I'm just getting my feet wet with regex, have browsed a few websites but can't figure this one out. I don't get why just the file extensions are getting matched, when their file paths/urls do not match the rest of my pattern.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you running this regex in javascript, then?

Comment: It's on an app on my Android phone, Tasker. Which I'm assuming would be javascript, yes. Right now I am just testing this on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ which seems to behave the same way as the app on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem that jumps right out at me is the end there. `gif|png|jpg` should really be `(gif|jpg|png)` - with what you have now, the string can match `webcomic"\ssrc="http://www\.explosm\.net/[a-zA-Z/]+\.gif`, or it can match just `png` or `jpg"\s`. With the parentheses, it will match `webcomic"\ssrc="http://www\.explosm\.net/[a-zA-Z/]+\.` followed by (`gif` or `jpg` or `png`), and then followed by `"\s`.

Comment: Bingo, that was it. Thanks man. It says I have to wait 1 minute before I click the "answered" check mark.  I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

That last bit

```
gif|png|jpg
```

means "match any of the three".  If want it to match just gif, write just gif.

Comment: Thank you. I do need to match any of the three though, as it can be any one of them depending on the day.

Comment: I didn't understand your problem -- I thought you were trying to eliminate the alternation, not repair it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a regex like this:

`\shttp://www.explosm.net\/[a-zA-Z]+\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)\s`